# Best way to pass value to a custom QtWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm still learning C++ and Qt and I was wondering what is the best way to pass a value between multiple elements without making too many connections.

At the moment, I've a widget `SamplerModule` where I've put many custom `QPushButton` (which is `ChordSelector`). 
In this widget, I've made one connection for each of the buttons with:

```
connect(ui->btn_accords_X, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->btn_accords_X, SLOT(changeChor()));
```

With `X` from `01` to `12`.

At the moment, when I click on a button it just changes the color of this button. But I also would like to set a text for it with a value which is available in my `SamplerModule` Class. And each time I click on this button, I would like to return an incremented value.

So I've thought about making this with 3 connections:

1. `click()(ChordSelector)->change()(ChordSelector)` to change the button color and increment my value, an int witch specifies my chord.
2. `newChord(int) (ChordSelector) -> updateChord(int) (SamplerModule)` to notify my widget that a chord has been changed
3. `changeText(QString) (SamplerModule) -> setText(QString) (ChordSelector)`

So this way should work, but as I have 12 buttons, I would need 36 connections just to do this little trick. 
Do you guys have some advise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using QtDesigner, then `QPushButton` will have a default slot, named `on_yourButtonName_clicked()`. It will auto connect to `click()` signal of your `QPushButton`. This may save the first connection.
2. Hold a pointer to `SamplerModule` in `ChordSelector`, or have a global singleton instance of `SamplerModule`, so it can be accessed easily in `ChordSelector`. In this way, you don't have to use signal/slot to call `updateChord(int)`, a simple function call would do the trick. This will save the second connection.
3. And you can call `setText(QString)` in `ChordSelector`'s slot of `click()`, rather than in `SampleModule`. This will save the third connection.

Comment: Thanks mate,
So first, I don't understand why on_yourButtonName_clicked() would save a connect. It just replace click() slot with on_yourButtonName_clicked() ?

Then, as I'm just a beginner in C++ that's part of my question, I'm trying to access data of `SamplerModule` within `ChordSelector` so using an other header with and `extern` variable would be a solution but it does not seem the right way to do it. As I can't included `SamplerModule` in `ChordSelector` and don't know how to do it. What's the right way to "hold the pointer" in this Class ?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. You can consider `on_yourButtonName_clicked()` as an auto-connect slot. So you don't have to manually connect it. 2. Could `ChordSelector `  be a singleton instance (only one instance globally)? If so, you can implement as a singleton class. Please see [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for more information about singleton class.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to implement that!